# How to reload only one controller on url change in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router for my web application and I have defined 3 different views: header, content and menu.

When I choose a link from menu I want only to reload content view, rest of page should stay as it is.
This is my route config:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider.state('', {
        url: '/name=:name',
        views: {
            header: {
                templateUrl: '/new/app/components/header/headerView.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController'
            },
            content: {
                // only this one should reload itself on url change.
                templateUrl: '/new/app/components/content/contentView.html',
                controller: 'ContentController'
            },
            menu: {
                templateUrl: '/new/app/components/menu/menuView.html',
                controller: 'MenuController'
            }
        }
    });
}
]);
```

In html I have defined this views like this:

```
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="menu"></div>
```

How can I define my config file to reload only "content" view?

Comment: If `header` and `menu` will always exist, do they need to be part of router states at all?

Comment: You are right. That solves my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create directives for your `header` and `menu` , or use `ng-include` and not use `ui-view` or put them into your states configuration

```
<div site-header></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div site-menu></div>
```